# Selecting a specific text node with phpQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, xpath, textnode, phpquery

OK, this is driving me nuts.  I'm trying to screen-scrape the following bit of seemingly trivial HTML with phpQuery:

```
<td><nobr>10-05-2009</nobr><br>06:10<br>17:35 -1</td>
```

The date is easy since it's wrapped in the nobr tag, so eg. `$element[':first-child']->text()` does the trick.  **But how do I get my grubby mitts on the second bit of text?**

CSS works on elements only, so `nth-child(2),(3)` return the surrounding `<br>` tags, not the text.

If I could XPath it, the second node in `.//text()` would be gold.  But apparently in phpQuery-land, the context for `$element->xpath->query('.//text()')` is the document root, so I get every single piece of text in the entire document!

Ideas?  All the solutions in [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) appear to involve Javascript DOM operations, which are considerably less evil than PHP's terrible DOM API.  Maybe just dumping the entire element to string and exploding it on `<br>` is the way to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

> DOMNodeList **DOMXPath::query** (
>   string *$expression* [, DOMNode
>   *$contextnode* [, boolean *$registerNodeNS* = *true* ]] )

So, this should work with `td` as context node:

```
$element->xpath->query('text()[1]',$element)
```

Comment: Thanks, that basically works, but you need to pass in a DOMNode (instead of a phpQueryObject) and then convert back the result, and for reasons I don't really understand the XPath selector `.//text()[1]` does not work but `xpath->query('.//text()')->item(1)` does.  So the final code ends up like this: `$src_time = pq($element)->xpath->query('.//text()', $element)->item(1); $src_time = pq($src_time)->text();`

Pretty monstrous, but gets the job done, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterating through the text methods of `$element[':first-child']->siblings()`?  That should give you access to all of their text, no?

Comment: Afraid not -- siblings returns just the two <br> tags.

Comment: OH!  Ok.  Sorry, I misread the br's (I thought one was an open tag and the other a closing tag for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Using Alejandro's answer as the base, I came up with this little function:

```
function nth_text($element, $n) {
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($element->ownerDocument);
  return $xpath->query('.//text()', $element)->item($n)->textContent;
}
```

Incidentally, that's pure PHP DOM, no phpQuery needed (or allowed, the argument has to be a DOMNode or DOMElement).  And now the original problem is easy:

```
$src_date = nth_text($element, 0);
$src_time = nth_text($element, 1);
```

Yay!